# Contct Form 7 en Wordpress no envía e-mails

Tags: php, wordpress, formularios

Tengo la última versión de wordpress y del contact form 7 y la versión php del servidor que está instalada es el 5.5 (la última versión estable según tengo entendido). Es un servidor de pruebas. El problema es que relleno todo el formulario y espero y espero y espero pero nunca me llega el e-mail que me confirme que funciona. He buscado en internet soluciones pero no he dado con ninguna (vi [esta página](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) que requería del plugging Easy WP SMTP pero no he logrado que funcione, en el `Testing And Debugging Settings` me sale un error que me dice lo siguiente: `SMTP connect() failed.` He ido a esa página pero no logro entender lo que pone).

¿Alguno sabéis como hacer que el Contact Form 7 funcione? Me da igual que sea con ese plugging o de otra forma... he visto que es un error habitual pero lo que he probado no he logrado que funcione.

Comment: Que servidor smtp estas usando?

Comment: Buenas :) Uno que encontré en un video de youtube buscando soluciones llamado Easy WP SMTP . Me ha parecido que está bien, solo que quizás sea que yo estoy configurándolo mal. De todas formas si conoces uno mejor no me importa en absoluto cambiar, estoy de prácticas y hasta ahora no había tenido que usar nunca Wordpress, quizás no sea el mejor plugging el que he elegido :(

Comment: No, lo que quiero decir es si como servidor de correo estas usando, el servicio smtp de google, o si por ejemplo tienes instalado postfix para el envio, lo que quiero decir es que tienes que tener un servidor de correo funcional para poder enviar mensajes, Easy WP SMTP solo es un plugin para conectarse a un servidor y desde ahí enviar los mensajes.

Comment: Ah!! vale, te entendí mal. Como el correo de la empresa es de gmail, estoy intentándolo con una de mis cuentas de Gmail. Busqué la información de gmail en internet. Lo tengo configurado de esta forma: http://i.imgur.com/mndy59F.png  SMTP username y from email adress tengo puesto lo mismo y en la clave, tengo puesta la de mi correo. Recibí antes un mail en ese correo que decía que habían evitado un intento de inicio de sesión de google.

Comment: Ok, el problema se debe a la configuración de seguridad de las cuentas de google, para reparar ese error ingresa a https://myaccount.google.com/security, una vez ahí ve a **Aplicaciones y sitios conectados** y activa el **acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras**.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo hice :) Pero aunque ahora me aparece que el mensaje se ha enviado, no me llega nada al correo :/

Comment: Trata de enviar un mensaje a otro correo que no sea el mismo que esta en el campo FROM EMAIL ADDRESS. Aqui hay mas informacion del plugin https://wp-ecommerce.net/easy-wordpress-smtp-send-emails-from-your-wordpress-site-using-a-smtp-server-2197

Comment: Uy, fue un despiste mio eso. Ahora me ha llegado el e-mail, pero completamente vacío (tiene campos que son obligatorios rellenar o no deja enviarlo). Te dejo un mensaje de lo que me llegó: http://i.imgur.com/Yd6rU5I.png    No se por qué no me está cogiendo la información de los campos... los tengo puestos con div y clases y los corchetes del Contact Form 7. Así sería visto en Notepad++ el código: http://i.imgur.com/fpfcPRI.png   En el Debugging Settings si que me envía el cuerpo, pero no en el formulario de la web. Muchísimas gracias de verdad por la ayuda :)

Comment: Al crear el formulario en contact form hay una pestaña Email, puedes poner el contenido de la misma?

Comment: Si claro :) Te pongo dos imágenes para no achicar la pantalla y que se lea bien todo (los tachones son mails o el nombre de la empresa) : http://i.imgur.com/ohvZw4A.png  y  http://i.imgur.com/Gbrw03Z.png  . El mail es el mismo al que llega todo vacío. (No se como darte la respuesta como válida en los comentarios, por la del SMTP).

Comment: Acabo de poner una respuesta en base a los comentarios, si te sirvió marcala como respuesta, así otros usuarios pueden hallarla útil.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya la marqué :) Si, tenías razón, me faltaba poner lo otro en el cuerpo del mensaje... cuando hice el formulario y leí la documentación no lo vi y por eso no tenía nada puesto. Eres un genio, mil gracias de verdad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema del **SMTP** se debe a la configuración de seguridad de las **cuentas de google**, para reparar ese error ingresa a [myaccount.google.com/security](https://myaccount.google.com/security), una vez ahí ve a **Aplicaciones y sitios conectados** y activa el **acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras**.

En la pestaña email de contact form veo que la tienes vacía, deberías tener algo así:

[image: Contact form]

Donde dice `[your-message]` en base a las imagenes anteriores deberías colocar `[consulta]` ya que asi se llama tu campo en contact form.