# Crear un formulario que se envie por e-mail en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, formularios, email, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-imagenes

he creado mi pagina en wordpress y me gustaría crear un formulario personalizado que cuando el cliente envié llegue directamente a mi correo electrónico, el formulario tiene que enviar también imágenes.

### Ejemplo del formulario:

- Nombre
- Descripción
- subir imagen del problema

*Enviar.*

---

El caso es que no encuentro ningún plugin que consiga enviar ese tipo de formularios a mi e-mail.

Alguna idea de como podría hacerlo ? Actualmente he probado con contactform y con ultimate member que puedes realizar cualquier formulario pero no hay modo de redirigir las soluciones a un correo electrónico.

Gracias.

---

**NUEVO:** He conseguido que me envie un único correo , el resto no los envia y tampoco adjunta las imágenes correctamente.

Comment: Con el plugin Contact Form 7 se puede hacer lo que quieres. ¿Qué problema estás teniendo con él?

Comment: Sin duda que con Contact Form 7 ( https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ )se puede hacer lo que dices. Aquí tienes un tutorial bastente completo de su funcionamiento: https://fabianvazquez.es/contact-form-7-tutorial-configuracion/

Comment: Contact form 7 sería mi primera opción. También podes fijarte Ninja Forms.

Comment: he conseguido que se envié un formulario pero no se han adjuntado las imágenes  y ahora estoy intentando hacer mas pruebas y no envía los correos.

Comment: Contact-form-7 sin duda. Luego tienes muchos otros plugins complementarios para por ejemplo hacer multipage o pago con paypal que funcionan de maravilla con CF7. Si tienes problemas aplicando no dudes en comentarnos.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLUCIÓN:

Efectivamente al final la mejor manera ha sido usar Contact Form 7.
Descarga plugin:
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

El problema de envió y de las imagenes se ha resuelto por  completo al instalar el plugin WPmailSMTP poniendo como  Servicio de correo electrónico el predeterminado de PHP.

Descarga plugin:
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Aquí encontré la solución: [Contct Form 7 en Wordpress no envía e-mails](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10011/contct-form-7-en-wordpress-no-env%C3%ADa-e-mails)

Muchas gracias a todos.